# Create conditional mask for image based on Value channel of HSV image

Tags: python, opencv, rgb, mask

I have an image on which I want to lay a mask based on the values of the `value-channel` of the `xy`-pixel of the image.

```
def rgb_mask(img):
   r, g, b = img[:,:,2], img[:,:,1], img[:,:,0]
   intensity = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[:,:,2]

   mask_if_intensity_below_50 = (np.logical_and((0.85 * g > 0.95 * b), (0.95 * g > 0.85 * r)) * 255).astype(np.uint8)
   mask_if_intensity_between_50_and_200 = (np.logical_and((0.85 * g > 0.95 * b), (0.95 * g > 0.85 * r), (g - r + b > 30)) * 255).astype(np.uint8)
   mask_if_intensity_above_200 = (np.logical_and((0.85 * g > 0.95 * b), (0.95 * g > 0.85 * r), (g - b < 150)) * 255).astype(np.uint8)


   masked = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=?) # I typed ? because I am note sure how to include this in the code

   return masked
```

`img.shape` returns the following:

```
(720, 1280, 3)
```

How do I assign the correct mask to each pixel? Ideally, I don't want to use a `for x, for y`-loop. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can duplicate the mask to be 3D matrix before using `bitwise_and`.

You can duplicate the mask using numpy [dstak](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) function.
For example: `np.dstack((msk, msk, msk))` gets msk in shape (720, 1280) and return shape (720, 1280, 3)

In the following sample I assumed `intensity` matrix is in range [0, 255] (not [0, 1]):

```
mask_if_intensity_between_100_and_200 = (np.logical_and(intensity > 100, intensity < 200) * 255).astype(np.uint8)
masked = cv2.bitwise_and(img, np.dstack((mask_if_intensity_between_100_and_200, mask_if_intensity_between_100_and_200, mask_if_intensity_between_100_and_200)))
```

When the mask shape and image shape are the same, you can apply bitwise and.

Sample masked image:
[image]

Comment: I thought of another solution, converting mask to RGB using OpenCV: `masked = cv2.bitwise_and(img, cv2.cvtColor(mask_if_intensity_between_100_and_200, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB))`

Comment: Thanks Rotem for your time and your input. I am not sure how to apply your answers. Just to check, did I made it clear enough that I want to apply one of three masks for each pixel depending on the intensity of the specified pixel?

Comment: I suppose the term "apply a mask" is a little vague. Usually you have a mask with ones and zeros (or 255 and zeros) and applying a mask on an image means masking the parts of the image where the mask is zero, and keeping the other parts unmodified. Now you know how to build your mask, and you know how to apply a mask. Apply one of three masks for each pixel depending on the intensity, doesn't make sense, because your are building the masks according to the intensity of each pixel. I think it will be more clear if you post sample images.

Comment: I noticed you are using both 'img' and `frame`. Is it related to the problem? `frame` is not a parameter to `rgb_mask` method, and I didn't know if it's a second image, or a bug. `bitwise_and(img, img` makes no sense... In case there is only one image, what do you expect the final result to be (after applying the masks)?